# How do you get fancybox/lightbox + video.js v6 to work responsively?

Tags: javascript, video, fancybox, responsive, video.js

I found some code that gets fancybox to work to display a video using video.js. When you click on the link to the video it opens up fine but forces fixed dimensions and squeezing the video or displaying on smaller devices breaks the view.

```
<script>
$(function() {

  $('.fancybox').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.fancybox.open({
      content: '<video id="video" width="' + $(this).attr('data-width') +
      '" height="' + $(this).attr('data-height') +
      '" preload="auto" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"><source src="'
      + $(this).attr('href') + '" type="video/mp4" /><div>Your browser does not support the HTML5 video tag.</div></video>',
      afterShow: function() {
        // do this for the dynamically loaded video
        videojs('video', {}, function(){
        });
      },
      beforeClose: function() {
        // if you do not do this the video will keep 
        // downloading in the background
        videojs('video').dispose();
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

I understand this was not designed to work responsively however that is the goal. Here is a link to the sample I made up:
    http://dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/vjs/

How can this be modified to work responsively?

Comment: Interesting timing, I just now finished implementing responsive videos for fancyBox3 (youtube/vimeo and html5 video, too), so, please, wait for the next release.

Comment: In my case this would be for locally-hosted videos; this works for vimeo-hosting already with fancybox but we don't want to use vimeo or any other hosting services. We want the clean html5 player with video.js styling and functionality.

Comment: @Janis - Is there an ETA for when fancyBox3 with responsive (locally-hosted) videos will be available, perhaps a notification list?

Comment: It will be available in the next couple of days. Follow https://twitter.com/thefancyapps for news and tips.

Comment: Sorry for delay, but next release will be bigger update than expected, you can preview it here - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/gopGNq?editors=1000

Comment: Thank you Janis; we're ready for this. Which of the options in the preview uses a locally-hosted video?